# what does "managed" mean in Azure?

Tags: azure

I was reading an article on Azure Firewall.  It says

> Azure Firewall is a managed, cloud-based network security service that protects your Azure Virtual Network resources.

The word "managed" pops up in many articles on Azure resources but I have no idea what it mean.  What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **old** days a firewall was a rack-mounted device that ranged in size from a briefcase to several suitcases high. Someone had to install the OS, firewall software and configure it. Periodically the software needed updates or patches. If the firewall went down at 3 AM, you got up and went to the office to fix it ASAP. Every 24 months new hardware was installed. That also meant budget approvals, purchase order requests, waiting for hardware, unpacking, and storing the boxes. I think you now understand what "unmanaged" means.

Today, Azure (AWS, Google, etc.) offer firewalls as a **managed** service. Managed means they worry about the hardware, power, cooling, patches and updates. You worry about creating and managing the rules for your network.

You benefit from a nice user interface without all the management headaches.